# Displaying raster data on map in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a trouble with displaying raster data on leaflet maps.

There is an float NxM array and RGB scale. I want to add new layer with the colorful tiles. I tried just to draw rectangles, but it's incredibly slow displaying. I noticed method `L.GridLayer.extend()`, but I didn't find any examples of what I want (just simple grid with text of coords on each tile).

Can somebody give an example where the raster data displayed by this or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html), you'll see quite a few that do per-pixel raster manipulation, including:

- [L.TileLayer.BPG](https://github.com/balrog-kun/Leaflet.bpg): extends tilelayer, loading a tile means rendering a `<canvas>` and dumping its contents into the `<img>`
- [L.TileLayer.PixelFilter](https://github.com/GreenInfo-Network/L.TileLayer.PixelFilter/): loads an image and replaces individual pixels
- [Leaflet-fractal](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-fractal): Displays the mandelbrot set, calculating each pixel of a `<canvas>`
- [L.TileLayer.GL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL): Manipulate images with WebGL. Very useful and fast for heavy computations (fractal sets are several orders of magnitude faster) or manipulating existing images. Do have a look at the hypsometric tint demo; it will be useful if your NxM array is in any kind of graphical format (as the "terrain-rgb" tiles).